# Clean html text from tags using jinja2 and Flask

Tags: python, jinja2

Im rendering some crypto data using Flask and Jinja2 into an HTML. From the flask app I get two lists that are denominated winners and lossers. Once I have these lists I would like to render these info in html.

The issue is that in the page, the results are displaying like this:

```
>('BTC-XHV', 0.2225133102340911) 

>('BTC-SHIFT', 0.19557264796923357) 

>('BTC-SOLVE', 0.19080717488789234)
```

I want to remove the '>' character. I have tried striptags method, and others things but I cannot find a solution yet. Also if will be good to remove the '()'.

Thanks in advance.

My template has the following structure:

```
                 {% for asset in winners %}  
                          {{asset}}
                          <br>      
                          <br>                                              
                          {% endfor %}                                                       

                {% for asset in lossers %}          

                       {{asset}}    
                       <br> 
                       <br> 
                   {% endfor %}
```

I would like to display results without the > and () characters, like this:

'BTC-XHV', 0.2225133102340911

'BTC-SHIFT', 0.19557264796923357

'BTC-SOLVE', 0.19080717488789234

Comment: How does this character > gets into the lists in the first place?

Comment: No, the first item in the loop, comes without the > . Like this ('BTC-CMCT', 0.6130653266331658) 

> ('BTC-XHV', 0.2225133102340911) 

> ('BTC-SHIFT', 0.19557264796923357)

Comment: Have a look into regex. Like @gittert mentioned it depends how the > character gets into the list but I think you should be able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to iterate over the lists of tuples you seem to pass to the template. Something like this. I expect this to also solve the > thing.

```
{% for asset in winners %}
    Crypto name {{ asset[0] }};
    Value {{ asset[1] }};
{% endfor %}

{% for asset in lossers %}          
    Crypto name {{ asset[0] }}    
    Value {{ asset[1] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's not solved the main problem of remove the >, and brings the output in an horizontal layout, that I not like. I would like a vertical list,for that Im using the <br/> tag. The format now is horizontal:                                                                         
BTC-CMCT; 0.6130653266331658; > BTC-SOLVE; 0.23141034932598928; > BTC-XHV; 0.18902079649743203;

Comment: You are free to add <br> into my example of course, that is just playing with layout in html. As long as > is not part of the data in the list of tuples, I cannot imagine that my solution will display any < characters...?

Comment: Yes, the solution that you write, display the > character between the items in the iteration, but in an horizontal layout, instead of vertical. The ouput of your solution is above,

Comment: Can you do a print (winners) and post the output from terminal here?

Comment: Winners is a list of tuples. If I print winners the result is this:[('BTC-CMCT', 0.6130653266331658), ('BTC-SOLVE', 0.16997145281999848), ('BTC-XHV', 0.13534482758620692), ('USD-DGB', 0.10000000000000009), ('BTC-UP', 0.08872180451127824), ('BTC-CURE', 0.08132530120481932), ('BTC-SLS', 0.07420859675606961), ('BTC-EXCL', 0.06837110207243854), ('BTC-SHIFT', 0.06616838865684765), ('BTC-HYDRO', 0.06521739130434778)]

Comment: Can you add an exact copy of your template? Or make available on github. There has to be an error somewhere. Characters are not displayed by jinja by itself.

Comment: I can add a piece of the html here :      <h1 align ="left">{{Exchange_List}} Winners</h1>             

<div align= "center" {% for asset in winners %}></div>  
                              {{asset}}
                              <br/>
                              <br/>                       
                              {% endfor %}

Comment: Ok, I see the error. See how your {% for asset in winners %} is part of the div tag? That is where the > is coming from. Try not to put these kind of if statements within the tag itself, but around them. In your case it doesn't even make much sense as the div is closed directly after the opening div tag. Try the following example: {% for asset in winners %} <div> {{asset}} </div> {% endfor %}. And feel free to add the break lines again ;)

Comment: The issue was solved. I removed the <div> tag from the {% for asset in winners%}, and write the loop as following : {% for asset in winners %}  
                             
                              <p align="left"> {{asset}} </p>
                        
                                                                                
                              {% endfor %}

Comment: Yep that is about the same result as I said. Well done.